# Can I free a C string after using it with [NSString stringWithFormat:]?

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring

Can I free a C string after passing it to `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` with `%s`? For example:

```
char *str = malloc(...);
// ... populate str ...
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%s]", str];
free(str); // should this be here, or after I'm done with message?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can safely free the char buffer immediately after creating the NSString. NSStrings always copy data passed to them. This guarantees their immutability.

Comment: at this point is also good to give a study also to theses: the @"" returns always constant NSStrings, the stringWithFormat is a Class Method (you don't see the alloc) of NSString object and the returned object is type "the compiler care my memory management" with the ARC.

Comment: There are actually two reasons you can safely delete the C string here. First, as Matt Wilding suggested, NSString always copies data. Second, no sprintf-type function in any reasonable language or library is going to keep a pointer to your string around—it creates a new string by formatting all the parameters you pass it, and therefore it doesn't need any of those parameters ever again.